# How to prevent Spotipy from adding incorrect song to playlist?

Tags: python, spotipy

Working through Angela Yu's 100 days of code and am on a project where the user inputs a YYYY-MM-DD to search for a list of 100 songs from billboard top 100 for that date. Those songs are webscraped and added to a playlist via Spotipy. However, I noticed that songs from unwanted years get added. For example, if I entered 1996-11-15, a Bruno Mars song would appear on my playlist, which isn't from 1996.

To prevent this, I added more conditionals in the for loop to search for exact song name and artist name, then I added an empty list called "duplicate_check" where I would add a song name for  a song that's already been added to the playlist list. The problem with this is I get less than 100 songs now.

How do I get 100 songs that are exactly from the billboards top 100 for the requested date?

```
# Asks user to input YYYY-MM-DD.
time_period = input("What year would you like to travel to in YYYY-MM-DD format? ")
year = time_period.split("-")[0]

url = f"https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/{time_period}/"


# Initialize BS to parse url above.
response = requests.get(url)
webpage = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")


# Scrapes Billboard page to find song titles
song_titles = soup.select(selector="ul li h3")
song_artists = soup.select(selector="li ul li span")
artist_list = [artist.getText().strip() for artist in song_artists[0:700:7]]
song_list = [title.getText().strip() for title in song_titles[0:100:1]]

song_uri_list = []
# The purpose of this list is to prevent duplication by adding the song name to this list, once the uri is added.
duplicate_check = []

# Using params and header, creates a POST request to create new playlist on my account.
params = {
    "name": f"{time_period} Billboard 100",
    "public": False,
    "collaborative": False,
}

# Gets Access Token from .cache file generated after initializing spotipy API.
with open(".cache", "r") as file:
    data = file.read().split()
    token = data[1].strip(',"')

header = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

# Initializes Spotipy API.
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope="playlist-modify-private",
                                               client_id=SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
                                               client_secret=SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                               redirect_uri=SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI,
                                               cache_path=".cache"
                                               ))

# Creates a playlist on my account.
response = requests.post(url=f"{SPOTIFY_ENDPOINT}/users/{SPOTIFY_USER_ID}/playlists", json=params, headers=header)
playlist_uri = json.loads(response.text)["uri"]


# Searches Spotify for each song scraped from url via a unique URI and adds it to a list.
for song, artist in zip(song_list, artist_list):
    results = sp.search(q=f"track: {song} artist: {artist} year: {year}", type="track")
    for dict in results["tracks"]["items"]:
        if dict["name"] == song and dict["artists"][0]["name"] == artist and song not in duplicate_check:
            try:
                song_uri_list.append(dict["uri"])
                duplicate_check.append(song)
            except IndexError:
                print("no song found")
                pass


# Adds list of songs to playlist.
sp.playlist_add_items(
    playlist_id=playlist_uri,
    items=song_uri_list,
    position=None
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch more initially, 120 should suffice,

```
artist_list = [artist.getText().strip() for artist in song_artists[0:840:7]]
song_list = [title.getText().strip() for title in song_titles[0:120:1]]
```

and then take only 100 unique songs:

```
# Searches Spotify for each song scraped from url via a unique URI and adds it to a list.
for song, artist in zip(song_list, artist_list):
    # take only 100 songs
    if len(duplicate_check >= 100): 
        break
    results = sp.search(q=f"track: {song} artist: {artist} year: {year}", type="track")
    ...
```